# How to replace first and middle char in string

Tags: java

**I need to replace first and middle char in string but without builder and etc, just with replace but idk how to make it.**

```
String char = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input string with more than 3 char");
    if (char.length() < 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input");
```

I just made this code and that is it, idk how to continue.

Example: ***input - pniut***

I tried with smth like char.length / 2 but cant.

Comment: That isn't how string replace works https://www.guru99.com/java-string-replace-method.html

Comment: what if the string has even characters?

Comment: I guess I was wrong, I know. I've read that article already but there is no example to help me.

Comment: So, the first thing would be to get really clear on your *actual* requirements. What is the problem you intend to solve, and why can't you use a StringBuilder or other approach?

Comment: @Aomine Ignore that, i just need example how my code need to look, i will easy fix if my string has even characters

Comment: @GhostCat I want to solve it without StringBuilder. Okay, if I have a program that will show me an error if I enter the stirng has an odd number of characters, how to write a code to replace the first and middle character

Comment: @Aomine I will try, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your string to a character array,  and then swap the characters at 0 and middle position. Then convert the array back to String. e.g. I hard coded 2 here but like you mentioned in comments, you will need to figure out the character at the middle position.

```
String str = "input";
int mid = -1;

if(str.length() % 2 == 0) {
    str.length() / 2 - 1 
} else {
    str.length() / 2;
}

char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
char temp = '0';
temp = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[mid];
arr[mid] = temp;

String.valueOf(arr);
```

The value of the middle character, you will need to find out, like you said in the comments.

Comment: Okey, im new in this, so arr [2] doesnt mean second char, that mean middle? Sorry for bad English. :)

Comment: Yes, I hardcoded that value just to show you an example for the string **_input_** because character at 2, which is _p_ is the middle character as per your definition. But you can easily determine the middle character like `str.length()/2`.  This will give you the middle character for strings with whose length is an odd number. For lengths that have even values, you need to determine  either `str.length()/2 -1`  or `str.lenght()/2 +1` as the middle character you want.

Comment: Can you type a code for me with str.length () / 2, im new, and i dont know how to start with code

Comment: I dont think that this is really what he asked for, but at least you have some code here, which I did not provide ... so have my vote ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Your answer actually explains better than mine!!

Comment: I can live with that. A newbie accepting another answer than mine is still accepting an answer. Much better than those dropping a question, getting an answer and walking away. And if you like my answers, you can always click that upward pointing arrow icon, can't you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` objects are immutable, converting the original `String` to a `char[]` via [`toCharArray()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()), replace the characters, then making a new `String` from `char[]` via the [`String(char[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) constructor would work as shown below:

```
char[] c = character.toCharArray();

// Change characters at desired indicies
c[0] = 'p';                    // first character
c[character.length()/2] = 'i'; // approximate middle character

String newString = new String(c);
System.out.println(newString); // "pniut"
```

Comment: I dont think that this is really what he asked for, but at least you have some code here, which I did not provide ... so have my vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: not possible (for generic cases).

Meaning: all variants of `String.replace()` work by replacing one thing with another. There is no notion of using an **index** anywhere. So you can't say "replace index 1 with A" and "index 3 with B".

The simply solution is to push the string into a char[], to then swap/replace individual characters via index.

Comment: Can you give me a simple hint with code? Im begginer

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting the goal of the lesson is to learn how to use the API. So would start here [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Go to java.lang.String.

I would focus on the **.toCharArray()** method and the constructor that takes a **char[]** as an argument. You need to do this because a String is immutable, and cannot be changed. A char[], however can be altered, allowing you to modify the first and middle slots. You can then take your altered array and convert it back into a String.